# jQuery AJAX Request, Incorrect Syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

As can can be seen from my syntax, I am very new to jQuery. I am getting an error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

My Code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //trying to reload the content after 3 seconds.
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#div1').load("ajaxtest.php");",3000 );
});
```

Comment: have a look to my answer, I explained every case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //trying to reload the content after 3 seconds.
    setTimeout( function() { $('#div1').load("ajaxtest.php")},3000 );
});
```

If you need it to loop, this should be suitable:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //trying to reload the content after 3 seconds.
    setInterval( function() { $('#div1').load("ajaxtest.php"); },3000 );
});
```

Comment: Perfect =) but another question, How would I loop the AJAX reload? I thought setTimeout would loop the refresh, but it only appears to be refreshing once.

Comment: If you want it to loop, you want to use setInterval(). Edited my answer to make it loop.

Comment: I saw the edit, thank you very much =)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot, you will want to place you jquery action within a function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //trying to reload the content after 3 seconds.
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#div1').load("ajaxtest.php");
    }, 3000 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

well the problem is here `""` inside `""`

here is how you can correct it using escape character

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   //trying to reload the content after 3 seconds.
   setTimeout( "jQuery('#div1').load(\"ajaxtest.php\");",3000 );
});
```

**but passing string in `setTimeout` is considered as bad practices. So, you can try classic enclosure**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //trying to reload the content after 3 seconds.
    setTimeout((function(){jQuery('#div1').load("ajaxtest.php");}),3000 );
});
```

**to loop you instead use `setInterval`**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //trying to reload the content after 3 seconds.
    setInterval((function(){jQuery('#div1').load("ajaxtest.php");}),3000 );
});
```

and to stop the loop you can just use a variable like this

```
 var anything = 
     setInterval((function(){jQuery('#div1').load("ajaxtest.php");}),3000 );
```

and to clear at last

```
 clearInterval(anything);
```